# Consuming xml-rpc in java?

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I want consume xml-rpc(written in php) in Java.such 
host = HostUrl
address = /index.php

method = "retrieveUserDetails"

Comment: You have three question marks, but no question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [Redstone XML-RPC Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpc/). It's a lot easier to use than Apache XML-RPC.

Comment: +1: Redstone is indeed a lot simpler than Apache XML-RPC. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Apache XML-RPC, here is good client [example](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/client.html).